# Json modification under apexchart

Tags: json, ajax, apexcharts

I'd like to use Stacked Bar from APEXCHART's in my project. I need to prepare 'series' and 'xaxis' categories.
I'm getting Json data from async Task:

```
return new JsonResult(list)
```

And I'm getting result in Jquery as:

```
const response = await fetch('Index/All');
const result = await response.json();
```

I don't know how to convert received data from this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "CzasZleceniaZamkniete",
    "data": {
      "maszyna1": 19,
      "maszyna2": 15,
      "maszyna3": 6,
      "maszyna4": 82,
      "maszyna5": 14
    }
  }
]
```

Into that:

```
series: [{
          name: 'Marine Sprite',
          data: [44, 55, 41, 37, 22, 43, 21]
        }, {
          name: 'Striking Calf',
          data: [53, 32, 33, 52, 13, 43, 32]
        }, {
          name: 'Tank Picture',
          data: [12, 17, 11, 9, 15, 11, 20]
        }, {
          name: 'Bucket Slope',
          data: [9, 7, 5, 8, 6, 9, 4]
        }, {
          name: 'Reborn Kid',
          data: [25, 12, 19, 32, 25, 24, 10]
        }],
```

And also Aaxis Category names (Maszyna1, Maszyna2 etc ):

```
xaxis: {
          categories: [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],
          labels: {
            formatter: function (val) {
              return val + "K"
            }
      }
```

Apexcharts from link: [https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/stacked/]